# Short If / Else statement in variable equalling "left" or "right"

Tags: jquery

```
tpl = '<li class="left">';
```

I would like this, if my var text contains @Tim marshall: or @Mark Smyth: to return the class of "right" but if it doesn't it returns the value of "left"

I know my starting grounds would be something like this:

```
var contains = text. if contains 'this' || 'that' = 'right' : 'left'

tpl = '<li class="' + contains + '">';
```

However I'm not 100% sure how to do this.

Comment: Use `indexOf`.  Also, don't concatenate text directly into HTML.  It will work fine for a known string like this, but you're better off setting attributes on tags to ensure that things are escaped properly.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean. If my understanding is correct that you are warning me not to allow people to enter text directly, I have this elsewhere `tpl += text.toString().replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/'/g, "&#39;").replace(/"/g, "&#34;");` to combat that

Comment: Don't use something like that, let the browser do any replacement for you.  You're using jQuery, you can use `.text()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `String.match()` to test the string like so:

```
var contains = text.match(/(@Tim marshall:|@Mark Smyth:)/) === null ? "left" : "right";
```

Comment: This one broke my script for some reason

Comment: ah, tp1. needs to be text. but regardless, I cannot get any of these to work

Comment: My page is [here](http://rafflebananza.com/admin/index.html) and  [index.js](http://rafflebananza.com/assets/admin/pages/scripts/index.js) line 505 is where my snippets are in this question. On my page to test it's at the bottom right in the chat area. Got a bug where you have to click the box to enter though, you cannot hit enter.

Comment: @Tim They are case sensitive by the way. If you want it to be insensitive, change the regex to `/(@Tim marshall:|@Mark Smyth:)/i` and it should work.

Comment: Ahhhh!!! I was going @Tim **M** arshall:, just noticed in the script and it works but brilliant for the new none sensitive version, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var regex = new RegExp('/(.*)this|that(.*)/');
var contains = regex.test(text) ? 'right' : 'left'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ternary operator `?`.

condition ? trueexp : falseexp

`tp1 = '<li class="' + ( text.indexOf('@Tim marshall') != -1 || text.indexOf('@Mark Smyth') != -1 ? 'left' : 'right' ) + '">';`

or this, which is shorter:

`tp1 = '<li class="' + ( ~text.indexOf('@Tim marshall') || ~text.indexOf('@Mark Smyth') ? 'left' : 'right' ) + '">';`